# Elasticsearch geoip.location mapped to double and not geo_point

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, geoip, logstash-grok

I am running Elasticsearch version 1.5.2.
Logstash version 1.5.4.

Most of the logstash settings are default:

```
geoip {
      source => "ipaddress"
}


output {
  elasticsearch { 
      host => "127.0.0.1"
      port => 9200
      protocol => http
      user => searchguard
      password => somepassword
  }
```

In Kibana, when I try to setup tile map, I see this error:

> "No Compatible Fields: The "[logstash-]YYYY.MM.DD" index pattern does not     contain any of the following field types: geo_point"

I checked the mapping "http://localhost:9200/logstash-2015.09.15?pretty" and geoip.location is mapped as double and not geo_point.

Any suggestions how to map this correctly?

More info:

curl -XGET localhost:9200/logstash-2015.09.15/_mapping

```
{
  "logstash-2015.09.15": {
    "mappings": {
      "logs": {
        "properties": {
          "@timestamp": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "dateOptionalTime"
          },
          "@version": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "csbytes": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "geoip": {
            "properties": {
              "area_code": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "city_name": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "continent_code": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "country_code2": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "country_code3": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "country_name": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "dma_code": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "ip": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "latitude": {
                "type": "double"
              },
              "location": {
                "type": "double"
              },
              "longitude": {
                "type": "double"
              },
              "postal_code": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "real_region_name": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "region_name": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "timezone": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "ipaddress": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "log_timestamp": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "message": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "method": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "referer": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "scbytes": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "scstatus": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "tags": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "timetaken": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "useragent": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "username": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

curl -XGET localhost:9200/_template/logstash

This is empty {}

I am using the defaults. I have not edited the default template.

Comment: Can you update your question with the output of `curl -XGET localhost:9200/logstash-2015.09.15/_mapping` and the output of `curl -XGET localhost:9200/_template/logstash`?

Comment: Anwer's probably clear. If there's no predefined mapping for `geoip`, Elasticsearch will always index it as an array of `doubles`. You need to specify this in your template. It also applies for data types such as IP.

Comment: updated with the output.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [geo-point data type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/mapping-geo-point-type.html). Mapping for `geo_point` can be set up only manually ([if i am not mistaken](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/geopoints.html))